# Element properties change when appended as root node(JAVA)

Tags: java, xml

I need some understanding of how the following works, thanks in advance:

I get the output as:
    This is the xml:`<Pages/><Title/><Author/>`
    This is the xml:`<Books><Pages/><Title/><Author/></Books>`

Additionally,
    The service which calls getInfo fails(Unexpected Error while obtaining REST output:
    document node can have only one element node as child) unless I comment out statement1
    but I need to traverse down from the xmldocument using getDocumentElement etc

```
public Node getInfo(String param1) throws ParserConfigurationException {
     XMLDocument xmldocument = new XMLDocument();
     Element rootElement =xmldocument.createElement("Books");
     Element child = xmldocument.createElement("Pages");
     rootElement.appendChild(child);
     Element child1 = xmldocument.createElement("Title");
     rootElement.appendChild(child1);         
     Element child2 = xmldocument.createElement("Author");
     rootElement.appendChild(child2);
     System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
     Node xxxx=rootElement;
     System.out.println("This is the xml:"+nodeToString(xxxx));
     xmldocument.appendChild(rootElement); //<---------statement1
     System.out.println("This is the xml:"+nodeToString(xxxx));
     return xxxx; 
}

private String nodeToString(Node node) {//converts the node to string
     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
     try {
     Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
     t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
     t.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw));
     } catch (TransformerException te) {
     System.out.println("nodeToString Transformer Exception");
     }
     return sw.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            public Node getInfo(String param1) throws ParserConfigurationException {
        //method getinfo created
                 XMLDocument xmldocument = new XMLDocument();
        //xml document object
                 Element rootElement =xmldocument.createElement("Books");
        //created root element of xml document and its books
        <books>

        </books>
                 Element child = xmldocument.createElement("Pages");
        //element credated name page
                 rootElement.appendChild(child);
        //inserted pages i.e. child variable in root element 
        <books>
          <pages>
          </pages>
        </books>
                 Element child1 = xmldocument.createElement("Title");
        //element credated name Title
                 rootElement.appendChild(child1);
        //inserted Title i.e. child1 variable in root element 
        <books>
          <pages>
          </pages>

        <Title>
        </Title>
        </books>         
                 Element child2 = xmldocument.createElement("Author");
        //element credated name Author
                 rootElement.appendChild(child2);
        //inserted Author i.e. child2 variable in root element 
        <books>
          <pages>     
          </pages>

          <Title>
          </Title>

          <Author>
          </Author> 
</books>
                 System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                 Node xxxx=rootElement;
        //value of rootelemet i.e. books inserted in xxxx
                 System.out.println("This is the xml:"+nodeToString(xxxx));
        //value of xxxx node is converted and printed using nodeToString(xxxx) function which is after this function

                 xmldocument.appendChild(rootElement); //<---------statement1
                 System.out.println("This is the xml:"+nodeToString(xxxx));
                 return xxxx; 
            }

            private String nodeToString(Node node) {//converts the node to string
                 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                 try {
                 Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                 t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
                 t.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw));
                 } catch (TransformerException te) {
                 System.out.println("nodeToString Transformer Exception");
                 }
                 return sw.toString();
            }

    thts wht i understand according to my knowledge 

//this method convert node of xml into string format 

private String nodeToString(Node node) {//converts the node to string
     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
     try {
     Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
     t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
     t.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw));
     } catch (TransformerException te) {
     System.out.println("nodeToString Transformer Exception");
     }
     return sw.toString();
}
```

Comment: I agree with the info you provided but why is the output different before statement1 and after it? And why does the service calling this function not able to parse the data unless statement1 is commented out